# fixed div with 100% width overlaps scrollbar

Tags: html, css

As demonstrated here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/rVPqeL

I am using 3 simple divs and I want to obtain an effect of a "global" scrollbar that has to go **over** the header.

The html is very basic

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="header">
    </div>
    <div class="content">
    </div>
</div>
```

and here's the css:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}

.content {
  margin-top: 50px;
  min-height: 2500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

The scrollbar keeps going **under** the header div. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

i tried with replacing `position:fixed` with `position:sticky` and added `top:0` and it worked well for me, no more overlapping vertical scrollbar.

```scss
.header {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The below code does the trick 
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XbOxgp

```
.container {
  background-color: gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
  z-index: 2;
}

.content {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 60px;
  min-height: 2500px;
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly you want the scrollbar always ontop. To do so change your css to the following

```
html{
    overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Scroll on html will allow the entire page to have scroll while keeping header static and remove scroll from container.

Answer (score 1):

```
.container {
  margin-top:50px; /* create room for header*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: gray;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.header {
  margin-top:-50px; /* move up by 50px*/
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

fixed positioned elements have "no width and height".

Hope it helps :)

**EDIT:** See this pen: [This](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/oXmawE)

Ps. I guess you also want to remove the margin of `.content`

Comment: This is actually not what OP is asking for.

Comment: Literally every answer on this is saying the same thing: scroll the body. But what if you don't want to scroll the body? This whole thread is very low quality

Answer (score 0):

Remove `overflow-y: scroll;` from your `.container`

Comment: If this answer is correct, which I think this is not the case, why would OP even have added `overflow-y: scroll` to his code? I think OP wants to scroll within the container and not within the whole page. Right?

Answer (score -1):

put the `overflow-y: scroll;` inside the **body** element:

```
body {
 overflow-y: scroll;
}
.container {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
 background-color: gray;
}
```