# How should I change css style of fixed element to not crossing scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I have fixed(position property) element called nav-map. I want to set max width to that element.

```
.nav-map{
   position:fixed;
   left: 0;
   width: 100%;
   top: 0;
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

but in that case it covers my scrollbar and i want to avoid that.

[image]

please, help me solve the issue

full source code: 
http://codepen.io/borispinus/pen/adpEWa

Comment: add right: 0; ? prettty hard without the necessary code..

Comment: @Paulie_D content overlapping the browser's scrollbar is expected??

Comment: Related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31860526/fixed-div-with-100-width-overlaps-scrollbar

Comment: i tried to set right 0 but it didnt help. Tried changing overflow properties in many ways as well but without progress. full code by link http://codepen.io/borispinus/pen/adpEWa

Comment: @BorisPinus That's because... See my answer. `:)`

Comment: See some examples of all the fixed navs, have `body`'s padding top to be equal to the height of the fixed nav.

Comment: @BorisPinus You there?

Comment: @PraveenKumar yeah, i'm here . thank you, Praveen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that, your scrollbars are part of another `div`, and it would be nice, if you can bring the div below the fixed nav.

So in the `<body>` give a `padding-top` of the height of the fixed nav.

```
body {
  padding-top: 40px;
}
```

This is how I do for all the fixed navs. This is how it has been done. `:)` See how it looks here:

[image]

**Fiddle: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/QyqBZQ**